# More lines in a row

Tags: html, css

I have got a `<table>` with a single `<tr>`. In this row can be many `<td>`'s. Is there a way to show the `<td>`'s in a new line, when the line is full without using a new `<tr>`.

For example:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td> *line is full, new line*
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The `<td>`'s will be created dynamically, at the time, when it's created, i don't know where i need a break. That's my problem. Is there a css trick, to do the break automaticly?

Comment: You mean you've got a single `<tr>` and want a new line without a new `<tr>`, right? Why don't you add a new row? What is against it? Sure it's possible with CSS, making them act like blocks, float them and clear the one you want as last in the row. But it's dirty as hell.

Comment: you mean you have a single row `<tr>`. And why don't you use multiple `tr` with single `td`. Do you have any constraint?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. But you can always do `<br>` or `rowspan ` attribute on td

Comment: If you fix a width on you're td if the content is too long it create a new line...

Comment: the number of the datas will dynamically generated. That's why i can't use <br>'s.the number of the datas will dynamically generated. That's why i can't use <br>'s. if the line is generated, it can have so many data that it cannot be indicated in a line. This is why I need an automatic word wrap

Comment: If it doesn't matter that a piece of information is wrapped into a new line and falls into different column you probably don't need a table in the first place.

Comment: -1 After adding multiple `<td>` with only the condition if the  `td`  is full, it means it look like the paragraph or one block of content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `div`s for that instead of a table:

```
<div class="table">
<div class="tr">
    <div class="td">foo</div>
    <div class="td">foo</div>
    <div class="td">foo</div>
    <div class="td">foo</div> <!-- line is full, new line -->
    <div class="td">foo</div>
    <div class="td">foo</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Clearfix */
div.tr:before,
div.tr:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
div.tr:after {
    clear:both;
}
div.tr{
    zoom:1;
}
/* Float elements */
div.td {
    float: left;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Of course you can float your `td`s. If you use this CSS, your `td`s appears in a new line, if the row is to small:

```
/* Float elements */
td {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: The datas will be created dynamically, at the time, when it's created, i don't know where i need a break. That's my problem. Is there a css trick, to do that automaticly?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td rowspan="2">$50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And css:

```
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible, but I don't recommend it at all. Best practice is to a add a new row.

But, to answer your question, display the cells as block and float them to the left. Then add a `clear: left` to a cell. This will be the first cell in your new row.

Do mind that with this code you loose your tabular layout, meaning that the cells in the different rows won't have similar width (see the demo).

```css
td {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: .5em;
}
.newrow {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td class="newrow">4 with more content</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use flex display so that td's will automatically go to new line if the current line is already full.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Try BootStrap, and then you can add classes like this:

```
<table>
 <tr class="col-md-12">
  <td class="col-md-3"></td>
  <td class="col-md-3"></td>
  <td class="col-md-3"></td>
  <td class="col-md-3"></td> *line is full, new line*
  <td class="col-md-3"></td>
  <td class="col-md-3"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Hopefully it helps.